# Average rows of dataframe with duplicated values in more than n numerical columns

Tags: r, dplyr, duplicates, average

I would like to be able to use `dplyr` to average rows in which there are identical values in ANY `n` or more numerical columns, and an identical value in the `a` column.

If:

```
n <- 3
```

and

```
df <- data.frame(a = c("one", "one", "one", "one", "three"),
                 b = c(1,1,1,2,3),
                 c = c(2,2,2,7,12),
                 d = c(6,6,7,8,10),
                 e = c(1,4,1,3,4))
```

then I would like the first three rows to be averaged (because 3 out of 4 numerical values are identical between them, and the value in `a` is also identical). I would NOT want row four to be included in the average, because although the value in `a` is identical, it has no identical numerical values.

Before:

```
    a      b   c   d   e   
[1] one    1   2   6   1
[2] one    1   2   6   4
[3] one    1   2   7   1
[4] one    2   7   8   3
[5] four   3  12  10   4
```

After:

```
    a      b   c    d   e   
[1] one    1   2   6.3  2
[2] one    2   7    8   3
[3] four   3  12   10   4
```

My data frame is much bigger in real life and contains plenty of other columns.

EDIT:
Rows `[1]` and `[2]` have 3 identical values (in columns `b`, `c` and `d`.  Rows `[1]` and `[3]` have 3 identical values (in columns `b`, `c` and `e`. This is why I want them averaged.

Comment: could you expand "3 out of 4 numerical values are identical between them"? As I understand it, only the rows 1 and 2 should be grouped accordingly.

Comment: @sbartbit - row three has 3 identical values with row one (in columns ```b```, ```c``` and ```e```). I will amend my question to make it clear.

Comment: Should the similarities chain? Like, if row 1 has 3 values identical to row 2, and row 2 and 3 values identical to row 3, and row 3 has 3 values identical to row 4, should rows 1-4 be grouped together, even if row 4 and row 1 have no identical values in common? E.g., row 1 `1,1,1,1` row 2 `1,1,1,2` row 3 `1,1,3,2` row 4 `1,4,3,2` row 5 `5,4,3,2`. Row 5 has no values in common with row 1, but there is a chain linking row 1 to 2 to 3 to 4 to 5.

Comment: If so, this essentially becomes a graph theory problem. Within every `a` group, you need to calculate for each pair of rows whether they are "connected" or not (by sharing enough identical values). Then you identify connected subgraphs of rows that are to be combined via averaging. This is all doable (the `igraph` package will help), but it's a bit of work and computationally a bit expensive depending on the size of your data, so I want to make sure we're clear before we go down that route.

Comment: Hi Gregor, thank you for your questions. Similarities should not chain. I am looking to average rows that share identical values with other rows in at least 3 columns. Row ```[4]``` should not be grouped with others because it shares 0 values with other 3 rows (values should be compared column-wise). Row ```[5]``` should not be grouped because it has a different value in column ```a```.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here, I first group the dataframe by the column `a`. Then, for each sub-dataframe, I calculate a distance matrix based on the number of different elements between the rows.

The package `proxy` is used because it allows easy calculation of a custom distance.

Then, I perform single-linkage clustering and cut the tree at an height just above 1. This will ensure that every member in a cluster will have at least `(4 - 1) = 3` elements in common with at least another member of the same cluster.

Finally, I summarize each sub-dataframe by the cluster number `gid`.

```r
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(proxy)

n <- 3

df <- data.frame(a = c("one", "one", "one", "one", "three"),
                 b = c(1,1,1,2,3),
                 c = c(2,2,2,7,12),
                 d = c(6,6,7,8,10),
                 e = c(1,4,1,3,4))



df |>
  group_by(a) |>
  group_modify(~{
    gid <- if(nrow(.x) > 1)
               proxy::dist(.x, method = \(a,b) sum(a != b)) |>
               hclust(method="single") |>
               cutree(h = 0.1 + ncol(.x) - n)
           else
             1
    group_by(cbind(.x, gid), gid) |>
      summarize(across(everything(), mean))
  })

# A tibble: 3 × 6
# Groups:   a [2]
  a       gid     b     c     d     e
  <chr> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1 one       1     1     2  6.33     2
2 one       2     2     7  8        3
3 three     1     3    12 10        4
```

Here is an example dendrogram obtained from the first 4 rows:
[image]

Comment: thank you for this, I think I understand what this code does (conceptually at least). However, when I run it (on the example ```df```,  not my actual data), I get this error:
 
```
Error: Problem with summarise() input ..1.
i ..1 = across(everything(), mean).
x Can't convert a double vector to function
i The error occurred in group 1: gid = 1. 
```

I also wonder if I wanted to apply this filtering only to selected columns from my dataset (whose names are stored in a character vector, ```to_use <- c("b","c","d")```), how can I specify which columns to use?

Comment: @Wera I just ran the code and it works on my computer. Make sure that the code is pasted faithfully and you are running an updated version of R.

Comment: @Wera in order to limit clustering to columns specified in `to_use` you should change the `proxy::dist` line as follows: `proxy::dist(select(.x, all_of(to_use)), method = \(a,b) sum(a != b))`

Comment: Thank you. The code didn't work because I had an object called ```mean``` in the environment. Renaming it fixed the problem.

Comment: @sbarbit- can you elaborate on the syntax? I am wondering why does there have to be a  ```\``` after the ```method```. Does this define a custom method? I looked in the ```proxy``` help but I don't see anything there that would help me understand.

Comment: @Wera `\(x,y) x+y` is equivalent to `function(x,y) x + y`. It is the R-4.1 way to define an anonymous function. Some of the new R features are discussed [here](https://www.r-bloggers.com/2021/05/new-features-in-r-4-1-0/)